# What to do in CartoDB so that null/zero values are not shown on the map?

Tags: carto

I've created a map and want to present some data with the bubbles (supply-demand), but in some locations the supply is zero. I don't want the bubble to be on the map in those cases. How can I do it? Is there any way to set it up in the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When viewing your CartoDB table or visualization, click the 'SQL' button, and you'll see the base SQL query for your data.

If your value field is called "supply", simply add to the query to state:

```
SELECT * FROM myTableName where supply > 0
```

Then click "apply query" or CTRL+S to save the query.

You've now turned your table or visualization into a 'view', which you can change at any time.

This is the power of CartoDB and PostGIS in action!

Comment: Glad to help, @Paulina!